# How to extract documentation from vala code?

Tags: documentation-generation, vala

I would like to know if there is a tool to extract documentation from vala source files like `javadoc` or `doxygen` does for Java / C++ /...

I started to document my code with classic

```
/**
 * I'm a function !
 * @arg An argument
 * @return I return nothing
 */
```

Thanks,

Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Valadoc](https://live.gnome.org/Valadoc) does this. Instructions on how to use it seem to be a bit sparse.

Also, if you are writing a library that is to be used from both Vala and C, a quick test shows that Vala preserves `/**` documentation comments when writing out C code. You can then use a C documentation tool, notably [GTK-Doc](http://www.gtk.org/gtk-doc/), to generate documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I will use valadoc (I'm trying to compile it).

Answer (score 0):

Valadoc is the official tool to build documentation, but on some systemes, make install don't works properly (for me, under Ubuntu 11.10).

So you have to correct the rights on some files.

Take a look at this page : http://www.mail-archive.com/vala-list@gnome.org/msg07321.html